# A few questions about infinite sequences of left-adjoints $\ldots F_2 \dashv F_1 \dashv F_0$ in category theory.

Tags: category-theory

I'm sure this is well-known, but it is weirdly difficult to find information on this topic.

Some functors have a left-adjoint which itself has a left-adjoint. Consider the forgetful functor $$U : \mathbf{CMon} \leftarrow \mathbf{Ab}.$$

This has both a left adjoint $L$ (the free Abelian group on a commutative monoid) and a right-adjoint $R$ (the Abelian group of units). So we have $L \dashv U \dashv R$, hence $R$ has a left-adjoint that has a left-adjoint. What I want to know is, can this kind of thing go on forever? More precisely can we ever have an infinite sequence of left-adjoints, like:

$$\ldots F_2 \dashv F_1 \dashv F_0$$

without any of the adjunctions being equivalences? If so, can we also make all the $F_i$ non-isomorphic?

Other things I'd like to know:

1. How about two-sided sequences? $$\ldots F_2 \dashv F_1 \dashv F_0 \dashv F_{-1} \dashv F_{-2} \dashv \ldots$$

   Can this happen with none of the adjunctions being equivalences, such that all the $F_i$ distinct?
2. Can all this behaviour still occur if the domain and codomain of $F_0$ are posets?

Also, please comment if you know of a notation for the $n$th left-adjoint of a functor.